# 14.04 - key presses are ignored

Tags: keyboard

I pressed some keyboard shortcut by mistake - I don't know which one, and now each key press is somehow "translated" to CTRL+key, e.g. when I press letter 'a',  all the text on the screen is selected (when you press ctrl+a). Same implies to the visual keyboard, when I click on 'c' - ctrl+c happens etc.) How to disable this strange behaviour?

Comment: Try to set BIOS settings to default (exept booting options needed for Ubuntu as Legacy/UEFI mode etc.) maybe there is some issue? Are you on Desktop PC with USB keyboard maybe?

Comment: I am on notebook with plugged USB keyboard (normal one is currently out)

Comment: Is a Wireless mouse part of that USB combo? Try to disable the mouse and reboot, then check if Ctrl is working (terminal is easiest way to check)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your hardware and BIOS setup is, but you could still go trough the BIOS settings, check the [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallUSBKeyboard) on USB Keyboard, there are few steps to do on some BIOS settings, maybe you just need to correct some of them.

Also check the Keyboard Layout chart, if you can't find it use the terminal:

`gkbd-keyboard-display -l keyboard_layout`

EDIT: Also check the `Universal Access` under System Settings, deactivate `Sticky Keys`
That would be my best clue on the Ctrl lock.